# How to separate serverless code from local server code

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-codebuild

I currently have a static web app which is hosted on AWS S3 bucket hosting. The backend APIs are running on Lambda/API Gateway. I have a continuous development pipeline set up which automatically builds (using CodeBuild) and deploys (using CodeDeploy) my code from my GitHub repo onto S3.

The problem I have right now is that the code which is deployed serverlessly is different from the code I need to run on my local environment.

For example I want my local environment to call the API from localhost, but I want my production environment to call the API from a site like api.example.com. Also there is some code which is different in order to deploy to Lambda, which won't run locally without reverting the change.

Another example: locally the APIs run on an Express server, but on AWS the code needs to be wrapped in 
`exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {...}` to run serverlessly on Lambda.

My question is, how do I handle these differences between local and serverless in my Git repository?

Comment: "For example I want my local environment to call the API from localhost, but I want my production environment to call the API from a site like api.example.com" --> that can easily be solved setting up a local ```etc/hosts``` file, pointing to the desired ip (eg. if you're running on Linux https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421491/what-is-the-purpose-of-etc-hosts)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem to me that using Codepipeline, CodeBuild and Cloudformation for this could be a good option. You didn't specify what you are already using so I'm offering this as an example.

It will require some up-tooling to work. To get started you could have a look at CodeStar, which can get you set-up with a sample of this - that you could edit for your own purposes - in minutes. It can poll a github repo for changes on a particular branch to kick off builds.

In the pipeline you could have say 4 stages: Source (pull source from git), Build (CodeBuild to create the build artifacts), Dev/Test environment and finally Production.

The non-sensitive configuration you could keep in the git repo in different parameter files (for the cloudformation app stacks) for each different development and production configuration. You inject a different (json) parameter file for development and production (e.g. from the github repo) into the cloudformation stack as part of the deployment stage. Some of it you can also inject via parameter overrides (the come in handy where for instance you want to use "build tags" like commit id or whatever).

Consider using Secrets Manager for the sensitive bits like username/password pairs etc (or maybe all config - that's an option too). Use a Secrets Manager key per environment. Send the Secrets Manager key (dev or prod) to the given app stack as an input parameter (cloudformation). Pull the Secrets Manager key/values from the app code (use an IAM role to grant privileges to for the Lambda's to specific Secrets Manager keys) and use [secret caching](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/05/Secrets-Manager-Client-Side-Caching-Libraries-in-Python-NET-Go/).

Also, as an aside - consider using AWS SAM (local) if you are not already.

The purpose of this is to:

- Separate configuration from code
- Automate your builds and deployments
- Minimise scope for human error
- Help reduce or outright eliminate downtime during deployments
- Easy way to rollback (git revert for instance)

Comment: It is for non-sensitive configurations. How do I create and access these parameter files? For example if I only want to add the line of code `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"` into my `package.json` only in a dev environment.

Comment: That really depends on your pipeline and build step. You could inject configuration via npm scripts you run during build (perhaps with an environment variable to designate environment). It could then do the copying around of configuration files (from two different directories - development and production) based on the environment variable.
In this way you inject the config and build - and which (development or production) is dependent on the environment variable.
Also consider using a different target directory (again via npm scripts) for development vs. production to avoid any accidents.

Comment: So just to clarify, I should have two directories at the root of my project, one for dev and one for production. During the build step of my pipeline, I should add a script to copy the file from the appropriate directory into root (for a package.json).  Also, to determine which directory I want, I should use environment variables (which I'm not sure how to use yet). Is this correct?

Comment: Actually, as bk2204 mentioned, the CD pipeline is only for production code, so I wouldn't even need the environment variables.

Comment: Still, if you are more than one developer on the app/service then you may want to include the development/production build (e.g. with environment variable) to ease the pain for your peers.
But essentially yes for the build step of your pipeline. I'm assuming the step can be customised somehow to run npm scripts via package.json (still I don't know what you're using so it's extremely hard to guide you on a once-size-fits-all basis but that's what npm scripts are for).

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can handle this. One of them is to set the correct data during a build step. For example, you can have a config file which is built with settings from the environment during your build step and default those options to the development options if they're not set. Reading settings from the environment, even during a build step, is a common way to implement configuration changes.

The other way is to have two configuration files, development and production, and use the settings from the correct one during build time. Your CD pipeline can know that you're building for production and use the right values from your configuration.

In general, using Git branches for this isn't a good choice, as it's likely to cause a lot of conflicts and unnecessarily copy settings from one to the other, which you probably don't want.

Comment: Can you show me how to achieve the first method? For example if I only want to add the line of code `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"` into my `package.json` in a dev environment.

Comment: I'm unfortunately not familiar enough with Node.js to write a snippet showing how to modify the `package.json` file. What build tool are you using already?

Comment: How would I add a line to any source file in general only in a production environment? I'm using CodeBuild as part of CodePipeline.

Comment: You would add a command to your CodeBuild build spec to add those lines as part of the build step. For example, you could use this command to edit a JSON file (in Ruby): `ruby -rjson -e 'd=JSON.load(File.read(ARGV[0])); d["proxy"]="foo"; File.open(ARGV[0], "w").write(JSON.dump(d));' versioninfo.json`

Comment: Ok thanks, that clears things up. Unfortunately I can't mark both answers as correct, but both were quite helpful.